# done button on numberkeypad is not working

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

I am using a text field to enter mobile nuber and I would like to add done button to hide the keyboard, following is my code

```
    - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {  
        // create custom button
        UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
        doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneup.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donedown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // locate keyboard view
       UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
   }
}
```

but I am unable to add the done button ,after cross check with break points , I observe that control is not entering into the   `if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"UIKeyboard"] == YES)` conditon.
I am using IOS5.

Comment: @stark Actually I am following this tutorial,   http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Comment: are you sure that this method is called when the keyboard appears?

Comment: @Novarg Yes.This method is calling but not enter into the if condition.

Comment: @Developer and are you sure that `tempWindow` is the correct window?

Comment: @Novarg could not get u..Correct window means? Please see this link..http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Comment: @Novarg I added the the text field as subview to the custom cell. Is this being the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did add a custom done-button in one of my projects too. The tutorial I used mentioned that piece of code:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2)
{
    if([[tmpKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == TRUE)
        [tmpKeyboard addSubview:doneButton];
}
else
{
    if([[tmpKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == TRUE)
        [tmpKeyboard addSubview:doneButton];
}
```

Prior to iOS version 3.2 your approach with UIKeyboard is fine, but later you have to change it to UIPeripheralHost.

Comment: Yes..I too tried this...but the control is not entering into the if condition.that is I am unable to run  [tmpKeyboard addSubview:doneButton]; statement weather in if or else condition..

Comment: May be i misunderstood, but did you change your condition to  if([[tmpKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES) ?

Comment: Well, as written here http://orta.github.com/code/imessage-style-receding-keyboards-in-uikit/ it seems that iOS5 introduced a new prefix. Try "<UIPeripheralHostView" as prefix, hope this helps.

Comment: Well, seems that it's finally time to cancel using this undocumented feature as it has been removed. Another way to rech your goal is the use of a KeyboardAccessory. You can read more about this at official documentaion: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html.

Comment: @valli ...i am facing the same problem ...is this working for you now?..if it is working please help me...